# "There sat the Shadow fear'd of man"

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, verbs, poetry

> But where the path we walk'd began
>            To slant the fifth autumnal slope,
>            As we descended following Hope,
>    There sat **the Shadow fear'd of man**...

(https://www.poetryfoundation.org/poems/45335/in-memoriam-a-h-h-obiit-mdcccxxxiii-22)

What does the fragment in bold mean? Is the Shadow afraid of man? Or does the Shadow frighten a man?

What is this grammatical construction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The next lines explain it "quite well":

> Who broke our fair companionship,
>
> And spread his mantle dark and cold,
>
> And wrapt thee formless in the fold,
>
> And dull'd the murmur on thy lip,
>
> ---
>
> And bore thee where I could not see
>
> Nor follow, tho' I walk in haste,
>
> And think, that somewhere in the waste
>
> The Shadow sits and waits for me.

The Shadow is death, (almost) obviously.

Now about "feared **of** man" - it is not common in everyday speech nowadays. We would say:

> "the Shadow feared **by** man"

or

> man being afraid **of** the Shadow.

You can test this using "bears", "vampires", "werewolves" instead of "the Shadow" to the same conclusion.

"Man" in this context does not refer to any person in particular, but to people (in general). As in:

> People are afraid of death.

Comment: Thanks; but who is afraid—the Shadow or mankind?

Comment: The man(kind) , of course. ( To be afraid of = to fear )

Answer (score 2):

"Man" in this case means "mankind", so a simpler way of wording that phrase might be

> There sat the Shadow feared by mankind...

Taking the whole poem in context, you see that "the Shadow" is another name for death.

"Fear'd of man" is definitely an archaic way of wording it, and I don't believe I've ever seen it outside of old poetry.